# Double stroke fonts with unicode-math like dsfont

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, blackboard

It is tempting to switch to `unicode-math`. But there is (at least) one point that I still don't like. That are the double stroke characters. They look simply terrible in `XITS Math`. Just compare:

[image: XITS Math]

with

[image: dsfont]

Are there any better options with `unicode-math`? At least they should be `serif`!

Comment: the choice to use the non-serifed blackboard bold in the stix fonts (the underlying font set for xits) was the overwhelming antipathy to the choice of a serif base for the blackboard bold in the amsfonts.  the model for stix was the original and traditional monotype blackboard bold, which was originally designed to "reproduce" the convention used by lecturers to render *ordinary* boldface on a blackboard.  (of course, blackboard bold has taken on a life of its own, and is now understood to be distinct from ordinary bold.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Well, I can't say where that antipathy comes from. Serif blackboard bold does fit much better with the normal math symbols. And those are neither used with serifs on the blackboard. That's why I find the choice made for `STIX` rather inconsistent.

Comment: the ams is one of the largest publishers of mathematics in the world, with a history of over 100 years in this endeavour.  when the amsfonts, with serifed blackboard bold (the first blackboard bold available for tex), was released, there was an outcry from mathematicians about the change in style from what they were used to.  styles do change, and other math publishers have since adopted serifed blackboard bold, but the sentiment among the stipub group that oversaw the stix development was to stick with the traditional form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately in `TeXLive 2011` this does not seem to work, but with a more recent version of `unicode-math` as in `TeXLive 2012`, the following can be used

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range="2100-"214F]{Asana Math}
```

This way the unicode symbols `ℕ, ℤ, ℚ, ℝ, ℂ` in [the `letterlike block`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/letterlike_symbols/list.htm) are set in `Asana Math`, which provides glyphs quite similar to the `dsfont` ones:

[image: Asana Math symbols]

To use it as `\mathbb{R}` one should set

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathbb]{Asana Math}
```

Comment: And `Cambria Math` from Microsoft Office 2007/2010 has serif double-struck capitals too.

Comment: @canaaerus Could you please explain you last sentence? I can't see a difference to your MWE provided in the beginning. The `\mathbb{R}` is not working for me, though. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It does work now.