# Double stroke fonts with unicode-math to match with Linux Libertine

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, blackboard

After reading this question, [Double stroke fonts with unicode-math like dsfont](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65313/double-stroke-fonts-with-unicode-math-like-dsfont), I remembered that the font which comes with OpenOffice ([Linux Libertine G](http://numbertext.org/linux/)) has a beautiful (but I don't know if useful) double stroke alphabet.

How could we use Linux Libertine OpenType with XeTeX and take the double stroke alphabet from that font.

You can see how is the double stroke alphabet in [this document](http://numbertext.org/linux/fontfeatures.pdf), at the bottom of the second page.

Comment: Does a solution have to use the XeTeX engine, or would you accept a LuaTeX-based answer as well? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico There is no problem if you post it (for future users), but in my case I know nothing about LuaTeX. In fact I just said XeTeX because the font is in OpenType, but if the solution comes in pdfLaTeX it would be perfect (to use blackboard in conjunction with `{libertine}` and `[libertine]{newtxmath}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbb]{Linux Libertine O}    
\begin{document}

Some text with the libertine font.

$\BbbA\BbbB\BbbC\BbbD\BbbE\BbbF\BbbG$ % from XITS

$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathbb{C}\mathbb{D}\mathbb{E}\mathbb{F}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't say it doesn't work, but I thought I already tried this and didn't work (may be I wrote something wrong). The “problem” is that if you substitute the `\setmathfont[range=…` line with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` you get that same output (the second in your example) with `\BbbA\BbbB…`… what? I thought that, since the `newtx` package doesn't have that blackboard, it wasn't included in the “original” Libertine. But looking in the font, yes, those characters are included. I hope they adapt them to work with the usual `[libertine]{newtxmath}` with nothing extra needed.